# windows 8.1 freezing up permanently once a day or every other day

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, freeze

### Desription

I built a brand new computer and the past couple of weeks I have noticed it freeze up permanently once every other day, sometimes once a day.

I have tried letting it sit to see if it comes out of it, but it does not. I tried interrupting it with ctrl-alt-delete and no luck. It just sits there with the monitor still displaying, but no input device works and it doesnt seem to be doing anything on the screen. I was able to open the dvd drive so that driver is still working...

I have had this same freeze happen during casual web browsing, playing games, or just on the desktop. So it does not seem to be application specific.

It will stay running for a day or two before freezing. It is easily fixed using a hard reset... but I should not have to hard reset a brand new $2,000 computer every day or two... It is extremely annoying.

### What I have done to troubleshoot so far

Updated all drivers. One at a time. None fixed the problem.

Let the system stay in a frozen state for 20+ minutes... No change

Let microsoft do all of its updates.

Tried interrupting it with all known interrupts

Installed CPUID HWMonitor to look at hardware. Voltages looked good (well within tolerance)

I did an intel burn test on my CPU and it passed it with flying colors on the most extreme version

I did a burn test (furMark) on my GPU, did not go above 78 degrees C. Ran stable for 1 hour at least.

Did x86Memtest+ (the one you boot to) and let it to more than 1 pass. No errors

Did a memtest that you run while windows is booted. Ran multiple passes, no errors detected.

Checked event logs, got some errors, but they all seemed benign, and I followed through with all of them to make sure they were not the cause.

I used my SSD's built in software to make sure it was good. Also ran chkdsk and the other microsoft tool that checks the file system. Everything came up clean.

I ran two full scans of Malwarebytes to rule out malware or viruses. Clean

I ran a full system scan with windows built in security tool. Clean. (I dont believe it is a virus anyways, I have literally only accessed video game servers and some imgur, and general email/facebook)

I have no minidump files, so it wasnt a catostrophic crash.

I heard hyper V being disabled could cause this issue, so I made sure it was enabled.

Another thread mentioned turning off a high resolution timer, did that too. No help.

I do have a western digital hard drive I use for storage, but I only set it up a couple of days ago, and this issue was present before that hard drive was configured for storage. I believe it is unrelated.

Called MS support, they mentioned how it "could be a virus" and tried selling me the "prime" tech support which i would have to pay for. Yeah right...

### I am running out of ideas, and I have googled this all over the place.

Any ideas? Is there better free software for analyzing my SSD?

I have a touchscreen laptop running 8.1 and it has never had any trouble like this before. I am surprised that this new desktop is freezing like this. It makes me wonder if it is a very cryptic hardware or OS bug related to some of the new hardware I am using (it is all pretty new afaik)

Any help would be appreciated.

### System Specs

http://pcpartpicker.com/user/dak8361/saved/ZfPv6h

### EDIT #1

I did have a problem with the original motherboard that was sent to me. I was able to install windows 8.1 on the SSD just fine before I returned the MOBO through amazon for the same exact model replacement.

Before windows 8 switching out a MOBO would cause you to have to reinstall the OS, but apparently it was a feature of windows 8 to allow MOBO switching for the same type of motherboard. Needless to say, I am typing this edit on this computer right now, so the MOBO switch worked just fine. But maybe it is whats causing the random freeze?

Comment: press the CAPS LOCK when you have the freeze. Does the light on your keyboard toggles or not?

Comment: I will try that if the freeze occurs again.

I tried rolling back my graphics card driver to see if the december 23rd driver that came out for my video card is actually the culprit. Time will tell. I will make a comment here if it ends up happening again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is frequent in Windows 8.1 *upgrade*. One of the most probable solution is to use **Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)** application; Developed specifically to resolve *component store corruption* in Windows 8.1.

Following link will be helpful:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. Since rolling back my graphics driver, I have not had a freeze, but I have not been using the computer as heavily the past 3 days, so it may be coincidence.
Will be stressing it out a bit more today.